# AT42QT1070 sensor output issues in standalone mode

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, esp32

Also when I am trying to see the data read on pins in serial monitor, it is not reading as required. The code i am using is as follows:

```
const int tuch_Pin0=18;
const int tuch_Pin1=19;
const int tuch_Pin2=21;
const int tuch_Pin3=22;
const int tuch_Pin4=32;

int State1=0;
int State2=0;
int State3=0;
int State4=0;
int State5=0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(38400);
  pinMode( tuch_Pin0,INPUT);
  pinMode( tuch_Pin1,INPUT);
  pinMode( tuch_Pin2,INPUT);
  pinMode( tuch_Pin3,INPUT);
  pinMode( tuch_Pin4,INPUT);
}

void loop() {

    State1= digitalRead(tuch_Pin0);
    State2= digitalRead(tuch_Pin1);
    State3= digitalRead(tuch_Pin2);
    State4= digitalRead(tuch_Pin3);
    State5= digitalRead(tuch_Pin4);

    if( State1!=0){
    
         Serial.println("Touch0 press");
    }
    else if(State2!=0)
    {
      Serial.println("Touch1 press");
    }
     else if(State3!=0)
     {
         Serial.println("Touch2 press");
     }
     
     else if(State4!=0)
     {
       Serial.println("Touch3 press");
     }
   else if ( State5!=0)
   {
    Serial.println("Touch4 press");
   }
   else
   {
    Serial.println("please press any key");
   }
   delay(100);
}
```

.....................the output it shows is... `touch press 0`.. without any touch and shows press any key when I touch any pin. Where I am wrong? Any solution, please?

Comment: Is it possible that multiple pads are touched at once? Then you shouldn't use `else if` but only `if`. Are you using a sensor board or did you build your own? What is the wireup? Do you maybe need to invert the logic so that `0` means pressed and `1` means unpressed?

Comment: it would make more sense to name the state variables `State0`, `State1`, etc